# What are the best practices for rendering excel sheet reports in Java?

Tags: java, excel, reporting, apache-poi, jexcelapi

I have a need to generate an excel sheet report which looks like the following template --
[image: Excel Report]

I know this can be done using libraries like **`JExcelApi`** and **`Apache POI`**. However I would like to know if there are means of accomplishing this by writing a template similar to writing `Apache Velocity` templates for sending emails.

If there is a standard, good-practice approach for generating such reports what is it?

Comment: The uploaded image was what i was referring to when i said 'template'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not create a styled template using Excel? Use placeholders (like ${name.of.field}) for the values that should be substituted, but otherwise style everything as required. Use a different placeholder to mark the end-of-template (this will allow you to write comments or other data beyond this space, to document your template).

Then, either via JExcelApi or Apache POI,

- open the template file, and locate the end-of-template marker.
- open the target file
- for each record, copy fields from the template, substituting ${xyz}-values for their actual contents
  and stopping once you reach your end-of-template marker.
- close target & template

Template modification will be extremely easy. The only problem is keeping the field-names in sync.

Comment: Upvoted. Sounds good. I'd like to open a bounty on this question to check if there are more alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: How is creating a 'styled template' different from using JXLS ? If not please edit your answer to include mention of JXLS.

Comment: Open a new excel document. Format it to your heart's content. Fill it with placeholders. Call it a "template", because you will be replicating it and filling in the placeholders later. If that is what JXLS does, my proposal is not to use it: where is the need? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard Java reporting library like [i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/de/products/clear-reports) and use the excel output format.

Comment: Propriety software is not an option for me as long as there are open source libraries that get the job done. Thanks though.